# Prestashop Backoffice controller - An error occurred while deleting the object (cannot load object)

Tags: listview, controller, prestashop

I'm developping a custome Prestashop Module and after struggling for weeks, I managed to fix most little issues myself. However, I am not able to get passed this error message : An error occurred while deleting the object. avanto_keys (cannot load object)

**My module name is** : avantokey

**Admin controller for list of table is** : AdminAvantokeyLogController

When I click DELETE on the row actions button, an error message pops up. Any idea why it can't load the object?

```
    class AdminAvantokeyLogController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->module = 'avantokey'; // valid module name
        $this->table = 'avanto_keys'; // DB table name where your object data stored
        $this->identifier = 'id_avanto_keys';
        $this->fields_list = $this->fieldList();
        $this->actions = array('view', 'edit', 'delete');
        $this->bulk_actions = array(
            'delete' => array(
                'text' => $this->l('Delete selected'),
                'icon' => 'icon-trash',
                'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected object?')
            )
        );

    parent::__construct();
    }

    public function fieldList()
    {

        $fields_list = array(
            'id_avanto_keys' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('ID Key'),
                'width' => 140,
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'id_product' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Product'),
                'width' => 140,
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'serial_key' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Serial'),
                'width' => 140,
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
        );
        return  $fields_list;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself suddenly in another Prestashop Module. This is what you have to make a table row deletable:
Add this extra line in the the __constructor method:

```
$this->className = "AvantoKeyTest"; // The class name of my object
```

Then you have to make a new object class. So, I made a new file : 'modulename'/classes/test.php

In this file I made this method:

```
class AvantoKeyTest extends ObjectModel
{
    /** @var string Name */
    public $user;
    public $comment;
    public $active;
    public $id_leoblog_blog;
    public $date_add;
    public $email;
    public $id_shop;
    /**
     * @see ObjectModel::$definition
     */
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'avanto_keys',
        'primary' => 'id_avanto_keys',
        'fields' => array(
            'id_product' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
            'serial_key' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => false),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: The solution was indeed to add the following line in the __constructor : $this->className = "AvantoKeyTest";
Then you have to require_once the path to the class : in this case AvantoKeyTest.php

Then create a : public static $definition method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ObjectModel for the table?

You need to specify it in constructor.

```
$this->className = 'myobjectmodel';
```

Comment: Hi there! 
No I haven't... So, I have to include this line of code in the __construct method.

Do I also have to make an extra custom objectModel then?

Comment: Either you do that or write your own `processDelete()` method which handles deleting rows. If you have bulk delete action you'll need to write `processBulkDelete()` method also.

Comment: Thanks. I will check also this answer if it works. Maybe its more easy then making a new class.